# chrome tabs.query search for new tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to [chrome.tabs.query()](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-query) for *new tab* only?
As per the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-query) I could not find any key in queryInfo object suitable for this.

[image: chrome new tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try querying with the `url` is `chrome://newtab/`